# Google Plus sharing URL with get parameter (even encoded!) not work

Tags: google-plus

I want to share this URL in Google+:
https://www.tropic.photo/shri-lanka?image=/assets/images/resources/64/shri-lanka-005.jpg

So, I use this link:
https://plus.google.com/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tropic.photo%2Fshri-lanka%3Fimage%3D%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Fresources%2F64%2Fshri-lanka-005.jpg

But when I share it, picture sended in '?image=' GET parameter not shown in G+ share window, but it must (Facebook and VK handles GET parameters fine, as is, even without encoding)

How to share link with image specified in '?image=' GET parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It's because my URL was contained dot '.' symbol before 'jpg'. I've replaced it with '$' ('%24') and I convert it vice versa on server side